# Retrieve contents from a JSON URL using cURL and display them in an HTML table

Tags: 7, services

I am trying to display contents retrieved from an external URL using JSON (the [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.curl.php) method). So i wrote the below function:

```
function file_get_contents_curl() {
  //JSON URL which should be requested
  $gry_str = "?timezone=" . urlencode(date_default_timezone_get())  . "&dateFrom=" . date('Y-m-d') . "&dateTill=" . date('Y-m-d');

  $json_url = 'https://www.example.com/json/financial-calendar.json' . $gry_str;

  // Initializing curl
  $ch = curl_init(); 

  //Configuring curl options 
  $options=array(CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true, 
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Content-type: application/json'),
    CURLOPT_URL => $json_url);

  //Setting curl options
  curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);

  //Getting resutls
  $results= curl_exec($ch); //Getting json result string
}
```

I want the contents retrieved to be displayed in an HTML table. So i am using this:

```
<script id="calendarContentTemplate" type="text/html">
<![CDATA[
  <tr>
    <td class="calendar-local-time"><%= time %></td>
    <td class="region"><%= region %></td>
    <td class="title"><%= title %></td>
    <td><%= forecast %></td>
    <td><%= previous %></td>
  </tr>
]]>
```

and my constructed table like this:

```
<table class="calendar-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="time">Time</th>
      <th class="region">Region</th>
      <th class="title">Event</th>
      <th class="forecast">Forecast</th>
      <th class="previous">Previous</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>   
    <tr>    
      <td class="calendar-local-time"></td>    
      <td class="region"></td>    
      <td class="title"></td>      
      <td></td>    
    </tr>   
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Nothing is being displayed on the table. Am I doing something wrong? Or do I need a Drupal function to make it work? Forgot to mention that its for the front page.

I have read about the [`drupal_json_output()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_json_output/7.x) function. But I am not sure if I have to use it. When I tried using it my webpage appeared only HTML.

It is very weird, because when I open Firebug I can see in the Net section. I am receiving **Status** as **200 Ok** for request, but the response is completely empty.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: May be you have to add `print  $results;` after your last line.

Comment: When i add `print $results;` after the last line it just print the results of the external json url to my homepage! and still the response in Firebug is empty!! Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Please note that i am using wamp server on localhost, but the request is made to my website.

Comment: Hey, then try `echo $results;`

Comment: Also I am not sure what does `$results` variable look like. If needed, encode that variable like this `json_encode($results)` and then echo .. `echo json_encode($results);`

Comment: No luck again print $results and echo $results even when i encode &results at the very top of my front page i get the content of the external url requested. :S And still Firebug response is empty:S pfff Any other issue that might have done wrong??

Comment: Do you think that is because of the wamp server?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4330/discussion-between-nicole-and-minty)

Comment: So i have put the json file locally (for debugging purposes)and the contents are retrieved to my html table. So i guess is something wrong with the retrieval of external URL. :S:S

Comment: You cannot make an ajax request outside of your domain because of [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). In order to do that, you have to use jsonp. It will look something like this `jQuery.getJSON("http://example.com/path_to_your_jsonfile.json&callback=?", function(responsedata){ call_appropriate_function(responsedata);} );` The black magic is `&callback=?` at the end of the your json url.

Comment: Hi, If you retrieve a error code from the api server this could be still correct. So if the specification of the api says (hhaha or omit) we response empty because we a reason this is still a valid 200 http response. So first check the api how they handle error response.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried drupal_json_decode? drupal_json_decode give you back a object that you can use for  print the variables.

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_json_decode/7